# How get emmet, php-mode and indentation of html work together?

Tags: php-mode, emmet

- I want `emmet` and `php-mode` work together.
- I want correct html indentation with `php-mode` enabled.

I know `web-mode` but I don't like it.

Comment: Please elaborate the question a little more. Emmet is little more than template expansion, and php-mode doesn't care much for html. I used to use those web-mode + emmet when editing MVC templates, which was ok for the occasional inline php,  and php-mode for the code files.

Comment: how to distinguish code files from occasional inline?

Comment: Controllers and models are code fashioned like most OOP languages, views are basically html templates with extra tags where some blocks may contain php snippets; for such task web-mode is fine. If you're going to intermix everything beyond trivial as if it were the late 90's or early 2000's there is no good major mode, and probably sooner or later you'll end fiddling with polymode or the likes. In fact html support in php-mode is legacy from the early days and somewhat discouraged.

Comment: As far as I understand, php-mode is only for straight php markup, and not mixed php/html. web-mode is for better or worse the best mode for this. Are you have issues with web-mode?